# Song from Tokyo Ghoul episode 10

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

What is the song that plays in Tokyo Ghoul episode 10 at 15:25 when Juuzou is on the screen? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This song is **Kriminalbeamte** by Yamada Yutaka. It can be found on the Tokyo Ghoul Original Soundtrack. (Disc 1, Track 9) Funny enough (*to me, probably obvious to you) it's the same song you were looking for in [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/36285/14969). This one was much easier to hear than in Tokyo Ghoul Root A ep 2 @14:15.