# What is this song in episode 2 of Tokyo Ghoul: Root A?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

What is the name of soundtrack in ***Tokyo Ghoul Root A (EPISODE 2....14:15) ?*** with the scene of Akira the daughter of Mado?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The song is called **Kriminalbeamte** by Yamada Yutaka. You can find it on the Tokyo Ghoul Original Soundtrack. (Disc 1, Track 9) If you want the soundtrack you can get it at [CDJapan.co.jp](http://www.cdjapan.co.jp/product/MJSA-1158).

Was not easy to track down since Investigator Takizawa wouldn't shut his mouth through the quiet music! lol